# Question about Training and Testing in supervised learning

Tags: keras, lstm

I am a bit confused and hope someone can help me.

I am currently experimenting with supervised learning. And I think I have a basic misunderstanding about the input and output of `LSTMs`.

When I have a sequence of 10 observations,

And I split it into `trains = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`

Also, `test = 9,10`.

And I transform it into a supervised problem like:

```
Xtrain= [(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)(5,6)]
Ytrain= [(3,4)(4,5)(5,6)(6,7)(7,8)]
```

And

```
Xtest= [(7,8)]
```

So the model is made to predict the next two observations from the previous two.

```
prediction <- predict(Xtest)
```

Is this illegal for a train/test split ? Am I correct that I can than evaluate the prediction output from `xtest` against the actual test set containing `[(9,10)]`

Or should I stop training at `xtrain =[(4,5)]` and `ytrain = [(6,7)]` to get some space between training and testing, since the last observations from y training in my example are used for the prediction
?